# Comparing variables of objects in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, compare

I've an array of objects in Java. Say these objects Obj contain a variable var, and I have several Obj stored in an array Array[].

I'd like to compare the var between two adjacent Obj but I don't know how, nor can I find any info online (which makes me think i'm working my question wrong or it's not doable or something)

Edit:

I'm currently attempting the rather roundabout method of assigning the array objects in question to new temporary objects and just doing the comparison with those:

```
Obj o1 = o[i];
Obj o2 = o[i+1];

if (o1.var > o2.var)
//etc
```

But surely there is something better.

Comment: Your code is very good already. I would leave it exactly like this. For example when you are debugging, you have the interesting things in variables so they are probably only one mouse click away when you need to look at them. That's the beauty of using many local variables, even if that makes the code a little longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of objects, you can do your comparison without creating the temporary references:

```
MyObject[] arr = //populated somehow
for (int index = 0; index < arr.length - 1; index++) {
  if (arr[index].var > arr[index + 1].var) {
    //your logic
  }
}
```

You might also want to take a look at the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface as a means of encapsulating the comparison of the objects based on a particular field. Using this interface would allow you to take advantage of its support in the [Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) API.

Comment: (deleted my comment: oops, your code really did go to length-1!)

Comment: @poundifdef: he edited it, your comment was correct.  I cannot believe this answer got marked correct.  I mean, it would produce an ArrayOutOfBoundsException (prior to edit) and wouldn't compile anyway (arr++???).  Sloppy.  Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, it would be fine to say

```
if (o[i].var > o[i+1].var) { ... }
```

assuming that `o` was of type `Obj[]`.

I'm curious, though: are you trying to sort the array? If so, you can use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) (If not, it's a good method to know about anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

I may not be understanding your question correctly, but the following is perfectly valid:

```
if (o[i].var > o[i+1].var )  { // ...etc... }
```

Beware of when you hit the end of the array! That is, if you are looping through all of the elements and `i` is the last one, then `o[i+1]` will give you an Array Index Out of Bounds error!

Answer (score 0):

Just use them directly without the reference i.e. substitute the array lookup into where you are doing the comparison.

```
if (o[i].var > o[i+1].var) {
    // etc
}
```

Or in a loop, doing every one programmatically:

```
for (int i=0; i<o.length-1; i++) {
    if (o[i].var > o[i + 1].var) {
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I had tried the solution:

    o[i].var > o[i+1].var

for a while before making this thread and was receiving some sort of error, but after closing everything down, going to work, coming back, and trying again... it just seemed to work. I'm not going to worry about what was wrong the first time, just going to enjoy that it works.